# UITableViewController: Scrolling to bottom with dynamic row height starts animation at wrong position

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a table view properly configured to have dynamic row heights based on Ray Wenderlich's guide found [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift):

I set up the constraints to have a clear line of constraints from the top to the bottom of the cell. I also set up content hugging and content compression resistance priorities and estimated row height.

This is the code I use to setup the table view:

```
func configureTableView() {
    // its called on viewDidLoad()
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureTableView()

    for i in 1...20 {
        messages.append([
            "title": "foo \(i)",
            "message": "bla \(i)\nbla\nbla"
        ])
    }

    // this is because the actual row heights are not available until the next layout cycle or something like that
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {self.scrollToBottom(false)})
}

func scrollToBottom(animated:Bool) {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: self.messages.count-1, inSection: 0)

    self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: animated)
}
```

And this is how I add new rows:

```
@IBAction func addMore(sender:UIBarButtonItem) {
    let message = [
        "title": "haiooo",
        "message": "silver"]

    messages.append(message)

    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: messages.count-1, inSection: 0)

    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom)

    scrollToBottom(true)
}
```

The setup with the default rows are fine. It add the rows and scrolls to the bottom as expected.

But when I add new rows after that, the scrolling seems to start above the last cell. As I add more cells, the offset seems to increase.

Here is a gif showing it happening: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3Lxs.jpg)

It's certainly related to the scroll animation (not the insertRow animation) because it scrolls properly when the animation is turned off.

Changing the `estimatedRowHeight` makes difference on the scrolling offset, but I couldn't find a value that fixed it.

I also tried delaying up the scroll using `dispatch_async` but it didn't change anything.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: From the video I can't tell what's wrong. And I don't understand what "... the scrolling seems to start above the last cell" means. Could you clarify? Making available an example project with the problem might also be helpful.

Comment: Dave, notice how cells 17 and 18 keep showing on the top on the screen when the scroll starts, when they where already outside the visible area of the table view. It looks like the screen moves up before starting the animation.

You can find the source code here: https://github.com/marcio0/ios-playground/tree/master/scrolltest

Comment: OK, I can see that in the video now (if I download it and go frame-by-frame). But I'm not seeing it in the sample project. I tried different phone models (but all 9.2) and also tried slowing down the animations, but never saw the issue you're having.

Comment: OK, I found it. I had to pass true to `scrollToBottom()`. That was set to false when I downloaded it.

Comment: FYI, hit Command-T in the simulator to slow down animations. It becomes very obvious then.

Comment: Sorry Dave, I might have changed that while trying randomly different settings. Thanks for the the tip on Cmd-T, I will update the gif.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wow, that was a fun challenge. Thanks for posting the test project.

So it seems that after adding the new row there's something off with where the table view thinks it's scrolled to. Seems to me to be a bug in UIKit. So to work around that, I added some code to 'reset' the table view before applying the animation.

Here's what I ended up with:

```
@IBAction func addMore(sender:UIBarButtonItem) {
    let message = [
        "title": "haiooo",
        "message": "silver"]
    messages.append(message)

    tableView.reloadData()

    // To get the animation working as expected, we need to 'reset' the table
    // view's current offset. Otherwise it gets confused when it starts the animation.
    let oldLastCellIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: messages.count-2, inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(oldLastCellIndexPath, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: false)

    // Animate on the next pass through the runloop.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.scrollToBottom(true)
    })
}
```

I couldn't get it to work with `insertRowsAtIndexPaths(_:withRowAnimation:)`, but `reloadData()` worked fine. Then you need the same delay again before animating to the new last row.